# AWS Lambda error - No such file or directory

Tags: javascript, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, serverless-webpack-plugin

I've deployed some code a AWS lambda and I am getting the following error:

`ENOENT No such file or directory found var/task/../data/cacert.pem`

The file it's looking for is within the lambda see image below:

[image]

I used webpack to add the file there :

```
{
   from: 'node_modules/tinify/lib/data/cacert.pem', to: 'app/../data/cacert.pem'
}
```

Can anyone help me understand whats causing this?

Edit:

The certificate file is being imported within the `handler.js` file see below:

```
let data = fs.readFileSync(__dirname "/../data/cacert.pem").toString()
```

Please note that the above code is added by webpack when it bundles the app and I can't edit that import statement. The certificate is needed by aa third party library (tinify.js).

Comment: Can you also share the code where you import the certificate file again?

Comment: @stijndepestel Hey, thanks for the comment. I have added the relevant code above in the my question. Please let me know if you need anymore info.

Answer (score 0):

You've got an error in the code that is importing the certificate. You're not constructing the path correctly.

You should use the following:

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const cert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, './data/cacert.pem')).toString();
```

`path.join` will construct the correct path based on the location of the handler file and the relative path between the handler and the certificate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.The problem is that I can’t edit the code that is importing the certificate. That code is added into the handler.js  file by web pack when it’s bundling the code. The import code is part of a third party library. 

Even if edit the code it will go back to its old state when I deploy the code and run npm install. Any advice?

Comment: The code that imports the file is wrong for where the code is located and it is trying to reach the file in a location where you will not be able to put the file in the Lambda environment. So this solution simply is not possible. This problem is caused by the webpack bundling, so you'll have to find a solution with webpack I think.